# Pushing from Xcode caused faulty commits - GIT

Tags: git, revert, git-reset

I wanted to commit B to the remote master branch whose head is at A. I had previously committed code saved locally (say X). When I pushed B to the master this caused the following:

```
 A-----B
    /
X--/
```

I just want B to committed. B should be on top of A and revert X commit. Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can `rebase` your branch on the commit A. Then revert the commit X.

To rebase -

```
git rebase <SHA of commit A>
```

You might need to force push if you want to change something that's already been pushed to the remote.